# Is is possible to have multiple SQL commands within one VALUES entry?

Tags: c#, sqlite, subquery

Is is possible to first insert an entry if not exist, and then retrieve the value in one VALUES entry?

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sections(data) VALUES(
    (INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Courses(column) WHERE column='test'
    SELECT id FROM Courses WHERE column='test')
)
```

So first I am inserting a value if not exist into Section where the value is referenced from other table. It might not exist, so I want to insert it and then I want to grab that 'id' of new Course entry.

Is is possible?

Comment: Dont think its possible. You might want to use a `CASE..WHEN..THEN...END` clause to check for null values, but that wont `INSERT` data into the second table

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood you correctly. I assume you want to:

1. Insert into Courses a new row with given "column" value if it does not exist
2. Insert into Selections the "id" value from Courses table, where Courses "column" has that value you just inserted in point 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database; it is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language, which can do all the logic.

Just execute the SELECT first, and then execute the INSERT if needed.

If the `id` column is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, you can get its value with [last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid):

```
using (SqlTransaction tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    string sql = "SELECT id FROM Courses WHERE column = @Name";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = ...;
    Object id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (id == null)
    {
        sql = "INSERT INTO Courses(Name) VALUES(@Name)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = ...;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        id = cmd.ExecuteScalar("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
    }
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find a solution that would work for my situation. Would you have an example?

Comment: I see, basically checking if query first returns a value, if not, then insert one and grab new id. Not exactly what I expected to see, but that will definitely do the trick. Thanks.